# Dropbox like sync service without real-time sync

Tags: synchronization, online-storage

I use Dropbox for syncing between computers and as cloud backup, but I a lot of my work is software and graphics based with either large files or hundreds of small files being updated very often.

Besides turning Dropbox on and off manually, is there a sync service (hopefully free) which has an option of syncing intervals like 'hourly sync' or 'at the end of day'?

Comment: a comment with feedback would be more productive than a negative vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered [Wuala](http://www.wuala.com/) which allows both 'backup' (interval based) and sync (continuous). It offers 5GB free and encrypts files before sending which is perfect for my needs.

[image: back]

Leaving this question open in case there are better options!